# Replace with next value (ctrl shift dot) in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone know how "Replace with next value" (ctr + shift + dot) works ?

I am unable to get this shortcut to do anything on my vscode.

I tried googling examples of this shortcut and asking on vscode gitter/reddit but couldn't get any answers.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could provide the steps of using this shortcut.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I press the shortcut after highlighting an integer or float literal (`16` or `5.2` for example) it subtracts 1 from it.

Strangely, `Replace with Previous Value` adds 1 to the value while `Replace with Next Value` subtracts 1.

I don't know if it has any other purpose.

Comment: Thank you. At least now I know there's one use of this shortcut

Comment: I agree. The naming conventions for what they do are confusing. Thanks for the answer. Does anyone know if they can be customized? Meaning, change the increment/decrement value?

Answer (score 8):

Add to the accepted answer:

1. If you use it on a boolean, it toggles between `true` and `false`.
2. No need to "highlight" the number, putting the cursor on it is enough.

Comment: I actually need to highlight the whole number, otherwise it just operates on a single digit under cursor.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @Félix Caron, this is how to swap the two keys.

`keybindings.json`

```
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+oem_period", "command": "editor.action.inPlaceReplace.up",   "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly" },
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+oem_comma",  "command": "editor.action.inPlaceReplace.down", "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly" },
```

Moreover, in my case as I have breadcrumbs enabled `"breadcrumbs.enabled": true,`, the replaceUp key triggered *breadcrumbs* instead, so I had to unbind it.

```
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+oem_period", "command": "-breadcrumbs.toggleToOn",           "when": "!config.breadcrumbs.enabled" },
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+oem_period", "command": "-breadcrumbs.focusAndSelect",       "when": "breadcrumbsPossible" },
```